# How to extract substring in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have multiple strings. They will be similar to

```
DEVSRC\2019\REL\19-REL-07\Sales\CustomerFlow\company.Presales.CustomerFlow.Web.UI.CustomerMobile\App_Themes\Bundles
```

and

```
DEVSRC\2019\REL\19-REL-07\Policy\XPM\Insured\company.PolicyManagement.WebSite.Customer.Components\content
```

In powershell I need to remove the "`DEVSRC\2019\REL\19-REL-07\`" from beginning
And
Everything after the "company.?.?.?"

I'm new to power shell and have been trying for a couple days

I have tried trim, substring, etc, but noting seems to work.

output should be

```
$mystring = "Sales\CustomerFlow\company.Presales.CustomerFlow.Web.UI.CustomerMobile"
```

or

```
mystring = "Policy\XPM\Insured\company.PolicyManagement.WebSite.Customer.Components"
```

Comment: PLEASE, would you show each input & the output for that string paired with each other [not both inputs and then both outputs] using code formatting?

Comment: so, I want to remove everything after "company.Presales.CustomerFlow.Web.UI.CustomerMobile" or "company.PolicyManagement.WebSite.Customer.Components". so, remove everything after the substring that has "Company.whatever.whatever.whatever"

Comment: strings all have same format but can be different. As you can see they are paths to different projects.

Comment: thanks! [*grin*] i _think_ i got it working. please let me know if it fails with other strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this uses a named capture group and a lazy capture that stops before the 1st `\` after `\companies.` in order to get the wanted part of the text. it is *fragile* in that it depends on a very specific pattern, but your two samples fit that pattern. [*grin*]

```
$InStuff = @'
DEVSRC\2019\REL\19-REL-07\Sales\CustomerFlow\company.Presales.CustomerFlow.Web.UI.CustomerMobile\App_Themes\Bundles
DEVSRC\2019\REL\19-REL-07\Policy\XPM\Insured\company.PolicyManagement.WebSite.Customer.Components\content
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $Null = $IS_Item.Replace('DEVSRC\2019\REL\19-REL-07\', '') -match '(?<Wanted>.+\\company.+?)\\.+'

    $Matches.Wanted
    }
```

output ...

```
Sales\CustomerFlow\company.Presales.CustomerFlow.Web.UI.CustomerMobile
Policy\XPM\Insured\company.PolicyManagement.WebSite.Customer.Components
```

Comment: @JamesLarson - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: Hint for a new contributor: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (once you've got a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of 15 it will be seen)

Comment: @JamesLarson - i see that LotPings answered your question ... when you get time, you may want to work thru the tour page here >>> Tour - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/tour <<< it also gives you a _nifty badge!_ [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

If the number of `\` characters is predictable, you can use `-Split` and `-Join` to make this a lot cleaner.

```
$s = "DEVSRC\2019\REL\19-REL07\Sales\CustomerFlow\company.Presales.CustomerFlow.Web.UI.CustomerMobile\App_Themes\Bundles"
($s -split "\\")[4..6] -join '\'
```

Comment: \ is not predictable